# Laravel: Order by Parent by a relationships AS column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following scope on one of my `Location` model. In my case, a `Shop` has a `one to many` relationship with `Locations`. The `Location` has a latitude and longitude. `$latitude, $longitude, $radius` are coming from a search field. I am trying to order `Shop` by the distance `Location` is from the user who is searching.

```php
public function scopeCloseTo($query, $latitude, $longitude, $radius = 25)
{
  $haversine = "(3959 * acos(cos(radians($latitude))
                 * cos(radians(latitude))
                 * cos(radians(longitude)
                 - radians($longitude))
                 + sin(radians($latitude))
                 * sin(radians(latitude))))";
 return $query
    ->select('*')
    ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
    ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$radius]);
}
```

and I am using it like so

```php
    return Shop::with(['locations' => function ($query) use ($latitude, $longitude, $radius) {
       $query->closeTo($latitude, $longitude, $radius);
    }])->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($latitude, $longitude, $radius) {
        $query->closeTo($latitude, $longitude, $radius);
    });
```

And this works fine, it lets me find all the shops within a certain radius.

What I want to be able to do is then order `Shops` by distance.

Adding `orderBy` to the `closeTo` in the closure just orders the `locations`. You can't order by `Distance` on `Shop` as it doesn't exist. How do I get around it?

Comment: I'm confused. Does a `shop` have coordinates? Can you provide a few rows of the results as they currently appear, and how you would like them to appear?

Comment: I've updated the question, hopefully makes more sense now

Comment: You have to use bindings for `$latitude` and `$longitude`, *never* include user input in a raw SQL expression. This is extremely insecure and vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Its not user input, its from an API, I just wrote it like this to make the questions easier to read

Comment: API input is also user input.

Comment: A shop can have multiple locations, right? Then order shops by their nearest location?

Comment: Yes, A shop can have multiple locations. I'm trying to get a list of Shops ordered by distance. But distance is computed, and not a column. so you can't orderBy on Shop. I was thinking of using an appended attribute, but I need to pass in the lat/long variables :/

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `distance` is a column on `location` because of the `AS distance` clause. There is no `distance` on `shop` because a `shop` doesn't have one and only one location. I'm still confused as to how you would like the results to be ordered.

Comment: If you aren't using pagination, you can order the query results: `$shops->sortBy(function($shop) { return $shop->locations->min('distance'); });`